# Redmine install on CentOS

Tags: centos, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine on CentOS 5 following the instructions on the [Redmine wiki](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_Redmine_on_CentOS_5). I've gotten to the "Configure Apache to host the documents" step without errors. 
That links to [another tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_configure_Apache_to_run_Redmine), and the fifth step is to edit the Rails path, but I don't have Rails at the specified path. Where can I find it?

Comment: I assume you didn't skip the step **Get Ruby**, so look at the output of `whereis ruby`, `which ruby` or `locate ruby` to see where ruby is installed and where the library files are.

Comment: This is the path: /usr/local/lib/ruby. And this is where I can't find the rails...